# How to enter tags correctly?

Tags: php, tagging, explode

I have a tag field in my web page, in which user can enter tags seprating them by `,` (comma), same as done in StackOverflow. I am using PHP and I am seprating all tags enetered by the user on the basis of comma using explode function and then adding them to my tags table in teh database.

My code is working perfect for normal tags like if user entered `battleship, strategy, sea war` then its working, but lets say user enetered `battleship, strategy, sea war,` or `battleship, strategy, games, sea war, , , , ,` or `battleship, strategy, games,, sea war` or any wrong value, then how will I detect it and then enter only correct value sin the database.

Is it possible using regExp or any other way, please tell me how?

Comment: tags arn't separated by comma in StackOverflow, are they? Thought it was spaces...

Comment: Yes, they are space separated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$tags = "battleship, stragety, ,";

$exp = explode(",", $tags);

$valid_tags = array();

foreach($exp as $tag)
{
 if( ($tag = trim($tag)) != "")
 {
   $valid_tags[] = $tag;
 }
}
```

Will remove whitespace from any tag and if it has any text, tag will be added into valid array :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions to split the string into the tags, for example:

```
\s*,\s*

$tags = preg_split('/\\s*,\\s*/', $str);
$tags = array_filter(array_map('trim', $tags));
var_dump($tags);
```

But then you still need to check if the tags are valid. An empty tag for example (like in `foo,,bar`) isn’t. Just filter them out and pass the rest to your database.

Or you use a regular expression to just find valid tags:

```
\w+(?:\s+\w+)*

preg_match_all('/\\w+(?:\\s+\\w+)*/', $str, $tags, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
var_dump($tags);
```

Comment: I think that is why SO is using spaces to separate tags, because if someone enters double spaces or single spaces in the last then we can trim it easily. ?

Comment: You can do that with commas and spaces too: `trim($str, ', ')`.

Answer (score 1):

No need for RegExps in this case. `explode` delivers the tag snippets, and `trim` removes white spaces. Just check, if then is something left.

```
$tags = explode (",", $posted_tags);
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    if ($value = trim ($tag)) {
        insert_into_db ($value);
    }
}
```

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = "ship,, , , , ,water";

$tags = explode(',', $str);

foreach($tags as $tag) {
    if( $tag ) {
        echo trim($tag) ;
    }
}
```

Comment: you may want to trim tags before inserting, in case somebody enters "ship, battle, naval"

Comment: I'm not quite sure, what the isset() does. $tag is set anyways, even if it is the empty string.

Comment: thanks. isset wasn't really needed, it's just that i'm in the habit of overusing it

Answer (score 0):

Better way is to suggest user what tags they can add - easy you can do it whit jquery ajax :) 
Some think like [here](http://www.ajaxdaddy.com/demo-jquery-autocomplete.html) (ajaxdaddy.com)

Answer (score 0):

You can *probably* get away with the very succinct:

`$tags = array_filter(explode(',', $str));`

since (from the manual for [`array_filter`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)):

> If no callback  is supplied, all entries of input  equal to FALSE (see converting to boolean) will be removed.

(That's if you don't mind rejecting '0', and other values that evaluate to FALSE)